# Silently stopping Liquibase at mid-update

Tags: java, sql, database, liquibase

Is there any way I can cancel a Liquibase update after I started it?

I've a list with around **5000** changesets, and I need to prevent all changesets from a specific point forward, to not be executed if a specific condition occurs in one of those scripts.

Since putting  **< preConditions >** in all of the existing scripts, and to all the new ones that will be created until the end of days, is not a doable approach, I was looking into an alternative and already tried the following:

- Created a **< customChange >** and throw an exception
- Created an invalid **< sql >** statement
- Added **< stop />** in the **< changeset >**

All cases work, but they also throw thousands of log lines (that I can't have), because I need a **silent stop**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was creating an include changelog file dynamically (for all the smaller changelogs) I simple iterate all the smaller changelog files until I reach the file from each things can be executed or not.
Then I execute a query to check for the specific condition, and if everything ran ok, I create another dynamic changelog file with the remaining changelogs.